# Regex does not work in

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I need some help. I have made a python script to delete lines based on a regex. I'm running it on my mac

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

inputfile = open('1.txt','r')
outputfile = open('2.txt','w')

outputfile.write(re.sub(r'^\d{6}$',"",inputfile.read()))

inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

The inputfile contains the following lines:

```
5420
3960
4830
164841
180007
164425
5603
4593
4701
6389
4898
12345678
6532
162912
165321
```

My script should replace 164841, 180007, 164425, 162912, 165321 with ""

But nothing happens, when I test the regex in notepad++ or sublime on my mac it findes the correct numbers

Comment: So you want to get an empty line or no line at all (instead of six-digit-numbers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `MULTILINE` flag to match anchors `^` and `$` in each line:

```
outputfile.write(re.sub( re.compile('^\d{6}$', re.MULTILINE), "", inputfile.read()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the file contents into a single variable. Just loop through each line from the input file and check against this `^\d{6}$` pattern.

```
import re
with open('/input/file','r') as f:             # open the input file for reading.
    with open('/output/file','w') as w:        # open the output file for writing.
        for line in f:                         # iterate through each line from the input file.
            if not re.match(r'^\d{6}$', line): # If the line won't have exactly 6 digits
                w.write(line)                  # Then write the corresponding line to the output file.
```